# ActiveAdmin associations - Don't permanently destroy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have an active admin form which looks like this:

```
form do |f|
  ...
  f.inputs "Special Interests" do
    f.has_many :special_interests, allow_destroy: true do |si|
      si.input :name
    end
  end
end
```

The problem is that when I destroy an association, I want it to timestamp a `deleted_at` field to mark the associated record as inactive rather than wipe it out. This could be achieved cleanly if I could somehow override the controller method where the model's associations are created/destroyed to substitute my own implementation. I imagine I'd want to do this inside the AA controller's `update` method, but not sure how to do it.

How does AA handle the `_destroy` attribute that's passed from the form? Is it all happening behind the scenes with Inherited Resources?

Comment: You've got some methods that AA gives you to override the controller. see: http://activeadmin.info/docs/8-custom-actions.html#modify_the_controller Have you looked at these yet?

Answer (score 0):

So I didn't realise that passing a `_destroy` attribute set to a truthful value along with the nested attributes, i.e.

```
{ model: { id: 1, example_nested_attributes: { id: 1, name: "Example", _destroy: true } } }
```

delegates to and is handled by ActiveRecord, which subsequently calls the `destroy` method on the AR model.

The solution was as simple as overriding the AR method `destroy` like,

```
def destroy
  self.touch(:deleted_at)
end
```

And all is good!